# Under Developer Story/Open Source (github) where do the ++ and -- counts come from?

Tags: support, developer-story

I see on my Developer Story, under the Open Source (GitHub) branch, the number of Commits followed by 272++ / 10--.  I don't understand where the ++ and -- numbers come from and what they mean, but they seem to be like/dislike counts.  Is that what they are?  If so, where does a reader get to add a ++ or a --? If not, what are they?

Comment: ++ number of lines added, -- number of lines deleted.

Comment: Seems like they've updated the service to detect when something was last committed, and what changes were mostly done to it.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't understand where the ++ and -- numbers come from and what they mean…

They come from *your* contributions to a GitHub repo. They show the number of lines *you've* added (`++`) and lines *you've* removed (`--`). Along with your total repo commits, this allows others to see how active you are in repos that have multiple contributors. We'll periodically check to see if you've added any commits recently, and if so we'll update your GitHub project information on your profile for you.