# Why are the GitHub statistics not updated?

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I added some open source projects to [my developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/19166) using the [Import from GitHub] button, but the statistics seem not to be updated automatically?

**Update 2018-04-09:**
This question was marked as duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361300/how-to-update-last-commit-in-my-developer-story).
I don't agree, because that question asks about how a user can update the stats manually. The answer was 'There's no way yet, but good idea'.
It also mentions that stats will be updated automatically. 
I understand (even expect) that.

My question is a bug report, that this update does *not work for me*.
It got 20 upvotes in 2 days, so I may be not alone.

Comment: Did you wait for a couple of days for them to be updated? What happens if you remove one of those and add back in - does it reflect new stats?

Comment: I waited several weeks. Re-adding reflects the current stats.

Comment: It should "automatically update every 7 days" ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361300/8601760), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358534/under-developer-story-open-source-github-where-do-the-and-counts-come-fr)).

Comment: I can see clearly on my developer story they are not updated anymore as well. Or we should take 7 days _very liberal_? And my github user name is filled in correctly as well. Should we post some kind of bug report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the late response. We haven’t had a team dedicated to the Developer Story in the last couple months.

We automatically sync GitHub user story items once a week as long as there is a push event in the last 7 days. There was a bug where we were skipping over user story items that incorrectly had Repo Ids set to NULL. Around 24k GitHub user story items were affected.

A fix has been deployed and your repos that had a push event within the last 7 days should be up to date.

Thanks very much for your report.

Answer (score -14):

According to [How to update “Last commit” in my developer story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361389/8246224), it should be automatically updated every 7 days.

And it is important that you need to set Github username set on your developer story/profile too.

Comment: Hmm, What is the wrong of my answer?

Comment: (I did not downvote, but) maybe because the question is rather about why this automatical update *does not work* for some users. I picked the project using the import function, so I'd expect to update afterwards. Where else can I set a GH username?